# Cannot update any packages on Linux?

Tags: linux, kde, kde-neon

All of a sudden, my package installs and updates from (apt) have started failing.

I'm on KDE Neon, and the message I keep getting looks like this:

```
E: http://archive.neon.kde.org/user jammy InRelease is not (yet) available (Connection failed [IP: REDACTED])
E: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease is not (yet) available (Connection failed [IP: REDACTED])
E: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease is not (yet) available (Connection failed [IP: REDACTED])
E: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease is not (yet) available (Connection failed [IP: REDACTED])
```

Any ideas what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. Why are Ubuntu IP addresses being retracted?

Comment: I'm fine with this being closed, I just wanted to get out the message that is a growing issue. I have also posted on Reddit/KDE Communities, so surely people in the same situation will know where to find this. It's a shame that superuser was not nearly as welcoming to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what many suspected, it my `apt` list of repositories was just fine. You see at the time I just happened to be on *public wi-fi* on vacation.

"Network is unreachable" can potentially mean that you are being blocked by the archive.ubuntu.com servers if they do not recognize your IP as safe. Switching to a VPN fixed the issue for me, as did returning home a few days later.

It's worth documenting that this error can be due to where you are connecting to the ubuntu.com servers from because I have not seen any other thread bring this up before.

Comment: [In reality the problem likely was a clock synchronization issue.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096930/sudo-apt-update-error-release-file-is-not-yet-valid)

Comment: That's not true, I was in the same timezone the whole time. Same for when I went back home. No "Release file is not yet valid" message here.